# preserving dynamic form data in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

My code is creating a dynamic form based on some xml structure.

 the form can contain many HTML fields like
text field
textarea
checkboxes
etc.etc.

After the form is rendered as HTML users can fill in the data.
After the user has filled in some values im checking wethere the values enter by the user is in proper format or not. in my controller by parsing the form collection.
If the entered data has some error then i add the errors to the `ModelState` using `ModelState.AddModelError("f2k0", "This Field is Required");` function.
But when I return the view because it is weakly typed I have no object that can be returned therefore the rendered form is lost and also the values that user has filled in are lost.

 I cannot use client side validation so only server side validation is required.

EDIT- the rules that iam using for validation are saved in `TempData`.
EDIT2 - this is the code in my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SpecialSurveyCode","Scan",new { codeId = ViewBag.CodeId, scanId = ViewBag.ScanId },FormMethod.Post,null))
        {
            <fieldset>
                @if (Model != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Keys.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var cntrl = Model[i];
                        ViewDataDictionary cntrlDataDic = new ViewDataDictionary(); cntrlDataDic.Add("cntrlId",
                        i); switch (cntrl.ControlType)
                        {
                            case ControlTypes.input_text: Html.RenderPartial("_Textbox",cntrl, cntrlDataDic); break;
                            case ControlTypes.textarea: Html.RenderPartial("_Textarea",cntrl, cntrlDataDic); break;
                            case ControlTypes.checkbox: Html.RenderPartial("_CheckboxGroup",cntrl, cntrlDataDic); break;
                            case ControlTypes.radio: Html.RenderPartial("_RadioGroup",cntrl, cntrlDataDic); break;
                            case ControlTypes.select: Html.RenderPartial("_SelectList",cntrl, cntrlDataDic); break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="formSubmitButton" />


        }
```

here the model is a `Dictionary<int,cntrlObject>`

Comment: You want to return same view with values if model is valid or if it is invalid?

Comment: in both the cases in need to return the same view

Comment: Can you post your view/fragment?

Comment: wow a downvote after 4 years!! and no comment

Answer (score 0):

Try to return view without model parameter. That method call return view filled by ModelState values.

```
return View("MyView");
```